# Displaying all images automatically in the gmail app?

Tags: gmail

Is there any setting in the gmail app to show images automatically when you open an email instead of pressing on the little links?

Answer (score 1):

Currently Gmail Released new App 4.7.2 with Auto Show Image feature By storing all images in specific server(Correct me if wrong).

[See here](http://www.androidauthority.com/gmail-4-7-2-android-app-update-auto-show-images-download-332448/)

[Link to Apk file](http://www.androidfilehost.com/?fid=23306841710657663)

Comment: Not seeing anything so far...

Comment: Featured Gmail App released..link is in answer.

Answer (score 0):

As for <strike>latest</strike> version 4.7.1 (946962), there is no way to show images automatically for all messages. **But for version 4.7.2 (967015) it is possible.** See [my other answer](https://android.stackexchange.com/a/60851/12677) to this question for more details.

In version 4.7.1 (946962) it works as follows:

1. By default when you receive a message, it doesn't show pictures and it
   displays a button to allow pictures  for this message.
2. If you click this button, all pictures will be displayed for this message, and there will be a button asking if you want to show pictures for all messages from the same sender.
3. If you click this button, the sender will be added to **picture approvals** list.

[image: Default behavior] [image: showing pictures for this message] [image: trusted sender]

You can clear such list from **Settings** menu, as indicated in the following screenshots. This way all messages will return to default layout (don't show pictures).

[image: menu > settings] [image: tap General settings] [image: clear picture approval list]

Comment: Ugh. This blows.

Answer (score 0):

Good news for you: Google is currently rolling out Gmail **4.7.2** (967015), which allows to show inline images without using the steps described in my previous answer. Here is what you'll have to do:

1. Download Gmail app update. You can either wait to be rolled out to your device or [download it from this page](http://www.androidpolice.com/2014/01/08/apk-download-gmail-4-7-2-update-adds-promised-auto-show-images-feature/) (because in this case it will be an app sideload, you'll have to make sure you enabled installation from *Unknown Sources* before).

   [image: Default behavior]
2. When installed, by default it will behave as previous version, i.e. showing the **Show pictures** / **Always show pictures from this sender** links, so you'll have to configure this to not happen (don't worry: this is done only once). Tap the overflow menu on Gmail action bar (not the message one) and select **Settings**. Then, in Settings screen tap your account.

   [image: Go to menu Settings] [image: Tap your account]
3. In your account, scroll down to **Data usage** section and tap **Images**. By default it will be selected **Ask before showing**, so you'll have to select **Always show**.

   [image: Tap "Images"] [image: Tap "Always show"]
4. Go back repeatedly until you get to your inbox. From now on, when you open a message, you'll be able to see inline images without confirmation.

   [image: Voilà]

**Notice**: This Images setting (**Always show**) will override the picture approvals state, so if you **Clear picture approvals** as shown in [my previous answer](https://android.stackexchange.com/a/59655/12677), you'll still see inline images in all messages, until you change the images setting back to **Ask before showing**.